# Is this a valid way of verifying solutions to a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I give you a non-exact ordinary differential equation $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy = 0$ and I ask you to prove whether or not some function $U(x,y)=C$ satisfies the differential equation. Is the following reasoning correct?

I differentiate $U(x,y)$ so I get $dU=A(x,y)dx+B(x,y)dy=0$, then I multiply $dU$ by some function $G(x,y)$ so that $B(x,y).G(x,y)=N(x,y)$, then if $U(x,y)$ is truly a solution to the differential equation this also must hold $M(x,y)= A(x,y)G(x,y)$, if I don't get an identity here then $U$ was not a solution in the first place.

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: you can just check that $M+N \frac {dU}{dx}=0$